# oracle soa 12c project convertion

Tags: soa, oracle12c, jdeveloper, oracle-fusion-middleware

I started working on 12c, my old soa projects are implemented using jdev 11.1.0.1.7 when I tried to open in 12c its asking to convert project to 12c compatibility, I just wanted to know what's happening on the convert project process?

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

What happens depends on the type of project.

*If it's a SOA composite:*
The 12c versions of the project and workspace files (*.jpr, *.jws) would at the very least have updated version numbers so that the correct 12c FMW libraries get referenced. 
There might be subtle differences in the *.bpel file formats as well (e.g. the BPEL version number or XPath version might change). 
On the whole, your components stay the same after migration (composite.xml, BPEL, Mediator, XSL etc.) but in 12c you get access to more (e.g. [end to end JSon / Javascript support](https://technology.amis.nl/2015/11/02/soa-suite-12-2-1-a-first-look-at-end-to-end-json-and-javascript-support-in-soa-composites/)).

*For OSB projects:*
When you import these into 12c, the process is straightforward like SOA composites but you get significant structural changes in the project all done automatically by the 12c import/migration process (e.g. proxy and pipeline split into two separate components).

The best way to determine precise set of changes is to **source control** your 11g project, migrate it, then perform a **diff** - if you use a good source control and diff tool (which is a must anyway), you should be able to see changes in altered files and also any new files created as a result of the 12c migration.